# Generating all the n-dimensional array in Matlab in which each entry can get only two value

Tags: matlab

I wanted to generate all the n-dimensional vectors that each of its entries can get only two values (e.g. for n=3 we get $2^3=8$ vectors) and put all these vectors into a matrix. Is any specific command for this purpose? I'll appreciate any help!

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure how this question could be answered. Yes, there is a command, and my answer showing that command was deleted. So I understand that is not the answer.

Comment: And so the question is still unanswered, because the simple and correct answer was deleted.